# How to use upsertField or upsert parameter in python script to import the json data in mongo collection

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, mongoimport

`mongoimport -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d my_db -c mycollection --jsonArray --upsert --upsertFields recipe_id C:/Users/mydata.json`

I am using above mongoimport query to import json files to mongo collection and it is working as expected. Here I am using recipe_id as unique filter parameter so while importing if a document have same recipe_id it can skip or replace the data and import only new data.

Now I want to implement the same thing in python so that instead of running it manually i can use it through python script. I tried to use upsert with insert_many method as one of the parameter, But it didn't work.

```
with open(import_file) as f:
  file_data = json.load(f)
new_collection.insert_many(file_data)
client.close()
```

As I am keep getting this json data on daily basis and this will contain duplicate data for sure, So I want to filter it while importing it to mongodb collection so that only the new data keeps on appending on the db and there won't be data redundancy.

Any suggestion will be very helpfull

sample json data:

```
[
    {
        "location_id": 11111,
        "recipe_id": "AB8974",
        "serving_size_number": 1,
        "recipe_fraction_description": null,
        "description": "1/2 gallon",
        "recipe_name": "ALMOND MILK 32 OZ",
        "marketing_name": "Almond Milk",
        "marketing_description": null,
        "ingredient_statement": "Almond Milk (ALMOND MILK (FILTERED WATER, ALMONDS), CANE SUGAR, CONTAINS 2% OR LESS OF: VITAMIN AND MINERAL BLEND (CALCIUM CARBONATE, VITAMIN E ACETATE, VITAMIN A PALMITATE, VITAMIN D2), SEA SALT, SUNFLOWER LECITHIN, LOCUST BEAN GUM, GELLAN GUM.)",
        "allergen_attributes": {
            "allergen_statement_not_available": null,
            "contains_shellfish": "NO",
            "contains_peanut": "NO",
            "contains_tree_nuts": "YES",
            "contains_milk": "NO",
            "contains_wheat": "NO",
            "contains_soy": "NO",
            "contains_eggs": "NO",
            "contains_fish": "NO",
            "contains_added_msg": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_hfcs": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_mustard": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_celery": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_sesame": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_red_yellow_blue_dye": "UNKNOWN",
            "gluten_free_per_fda": "UNKNOWN",
            "non_gmo_claim": "UNKNOWN",
            "contains_gluten": "NO"
        },
        "dietary_attributes": {
            "vegan": "YES",
            "vegetarian": "YES",
            "kosher": "YES",
            "halal": "UNKNOWN"
        },
        "primary_attributes": {
            "protein": 7.543,
            "total_fat": 19.022,
            "carbohydrate": 69.196,
            "calories": 463.227,
            "total_sugars": 61.285,
            "fiber": 5.81,
            "calcium": 3840.228,
            "iron": 3.955,
            "potassium": 270.768,
            "sodium": 1351.208,
            "cholesterol": 0.0,
            "trans_fat": 0.0,
            "saturated_fat": 1.488,
            "monounsaturated_fat": 11.743,
            "polyunsaturated_fat": 4.832,
            "calories_from_fat": 171.195,
            "pct_calories_from_fat": 36.957,
            "pct_calories_from_saturated_fat": 2.892,
            "added_sugars": null,
            "vitamin_d_(mcg)": null
        },
        "secondary_attributes": {
            "ash": null,
            "water": null,
            "magnesium": 120.654,
            "phosphorous": 171.215,
            "zinc": 1.019,
            "copper": 0.183,
            "manganese": null,
            "selenium": 1.325,
            "vitamin_a_(IU)": 5331.357,
            "vitamin_a_(RAE)": null,
            "beta_carotene": null,
            "alpha_carotene": null,
            "vitamin_e_(A-tocopherol)": 49.909,
            "vitamin_d_(IU)": null,
            "vitamin_c": 0.0,
            "thiamin_(B1)": 0.0,
            "riboflavin_(B2)": 0.449,
            "niacin": 0.979,
            "pantothenic_acid": 0.061,
            "vitamin_b6": 0.0,
            "folacin_(folic_acid)": null,
            "vitamin_b12": 0.0,
            "vitamin_k": null,
            "folic_acid": null,
            "folate_food": null,
            "folate_DFE": null,
            "vitamin_a_(RE)": null,
            "pct_calories_from_protein": 6.514,
            "pct_calories_from_carbohydrates": 59.751,
            "biotin": null,
            "niacin_(mg_NE)": null,
            "vitamin_e_(IU)": null
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the sample json data which I will be getting on daily basis. And in this recipe ID will be unique, There will be chances that same recipe is appearing on every file along with some new recipe. So want to append the new recipes only if it exist.

Below is the sample of database structure

```
> db.my_col1.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f20c8cc1cd23262e7c28e88"),
        "location_id" : 11111,
        "recipe_id" : "AB8974",
        "serving_size_number" : 1,
        "recipe_fraction_description" : null,
        "description" : "1/2 gallon",
        "recipe_name" : "ALMOND MILK 32 OZ",
        "marketing_name" : "Almond Milk",
        "marketing_description" : null,
        "ingredient_statement" : "Almond Milk (ALMOND MILK (FILTERED WATER, ALMONDS), CANE SUGAR, CONTAINS 2% OR LESS OF: VITAMIN AND MINERAL BLEND (CALCIUM CARBONATE, VITAMIN E ACETATE, VITAMIN A PALMITATE, VITAMIN D2), SEA SALT, SUNFLOWER LECITHIN, LOCUST BEAN GUM, GELLAN GUM.)",
        "allergen_attributes" : {
                "allergen_statement_not_available" : null,
                "contains_shellfish" : "NO",
                "contains_peanut" : "NO",
                "contains_tree_nuts" : "YES",
                "contains_milk" : "NO",
                "contains_wheat" : "NO",
                "contains_soy" : "NO",
                "contains_eggs" : "NO",
                "contains_fish" : "NO",
                "contains_added_msg" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_hfcs" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_mustard" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_celery" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_sesame" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_red_yellow_blue_dye" : "UNKNOWN",
                "gluten_free_per_fda" : "UNKNOWN",
                "non_gmo_claim" : "UNKNOWN",
                "contains_gluten" : "NO"
        },
        "dietary_attributes" : {
                "vegan" : "YES",
                "vegetarian" : "YES",
                "kosher" : "YES",
                "halal" : "UNKNOWN"
        },
        "primary_attributes" : {
                "protein" : 7.543,
                "total_fat" : 19.022,
                "carbohydrate" : 69.196,
                "calories" : 463.227,
                "total_sugars" : 61.285,
                "fiber" : 5.81,
                "calcium" : 3840.228,
                "iron" : 3.955,
                "potassium" : 270.768,
                "sodium" : 1351.208,
                "cholesterol" : 0,
                "trans_fat" : 0,
                "saturated_fat" : 1.488,
                "monounsaturated_fat" : 11.743,
                "polyunsaturated_fat" : 4.832,
                "calories_from_fat" : 171.195,
                "pct_calories_from_fat" : 36.957,
                "pct_calories_from_saturated_fat" : 2.892,
                "added_sugars" : null,
                "vitamin_d_(mcg)" : null
        },
        "secondary_attributes" : {
                "ash" : null,
                "water" : null,
                "magnesium" : 120.654,
                "phosphorous" : 171.215,
                "zinc" : 1.019,
                "copper" : 0.183,
                "manganese" : null,
                "selenium" : 1.325,
                "vitamin_a_(IU)" : 5331.357,
                "vitamin_a_(RAE)" : null,
                "beta_carotene" : null,
                "alpha_carotene" : null,
                "vitamin_e_(A-tocopherol)" : 49.909,
                "vitamin_d_(IU)" : null,
                "vitamin_c" : 0,
                "thiamin_(B1)" : 0,
                "riboflavin_(B2)" : 0.449,
                "niacin" : 0.979,
                "pantothenic_acid" : 0.061,
                "vitamin_b6" : 0,
                "folacin_(folic_acid)" : null,
                "vitamin_b12" : 0,
                "vitamin_k" : null,
                "folic_acid" : null,
                "folate_food" : null,
                "folate_DFE" : null,
                "vitamin_a_(RE)" : null,
                "pct_calories_from_protein" : 6.514,
                "pct_calories_from_carbohydrates" : 59.751,
                "biotin" : null,
                "niacin_(mg_NE)" : null,
                "vitamin_e_(IU)" : null
        }
}
```

Comment: can you post the sample json data and also how you are identifying a document as a duplicate?

Comment: @deadshot i have attached same json data and in this "recipie_id" will be unique for every recipe, So i don't wanna append the the same recipe again to the collection if it was imported yesterday.

Comment: did you try using `recipe_id` as `_id`? this will help [indexing](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#indexing) and another way is process your json and remove the duplicates then you can insert all your records with single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a unique index on the recipe.recipe_id field, or code around it by checking if a matching document exists or not:

```
with open(import_file) as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

for data in file_data:
    recipe_id = get('recipe_id') # Add error checking if any chance these fields don't exist
    if db.mycollection.find_one({'recipe_id': recipe_id}) is None:
        db.mycollection.insert_one(data)
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried above approach but it append the existing recipe again to the collection instead of skiping it. After inserting when i check for one specfic recipe ID i can see there are two entries for the same.

Comment: can you edit your question and add the result of `db.mycollection.findOne()` from the mongo shell to confirm the structure in the database

Comment: Hey Belly, i have added the sample structure of the database and updated the sample json data as well. As i mentioned above in the question i am able to successfully import the new data by adding upsertField in the mongoimport query. and it is working as expected. Is there a way we can use that parameter whilw inserting the data using insert_many or insert_one

Comment: I edited the answer following the additional information you provided. If this is now working [please mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10490683/belly-buster if my data cotains integer value as recipe_id instead of string how to access that  As this line is not able to check for integer values `if db.mycollection.find_one({'recipe_id': recipe_id})` , Can you help me out with that ??

Comment: use `int(recipe_id)`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10490683/belly-buster I tried that way but no luck it's not filtering if I try to run the code on same data twice it is appending all data again and again. `if db.mycollection.find_one({'recipe_id': int(recipe_id)}) `